# Is there a flaw in the Elsevier green OA license?

Tags: publications, open-access, elsevier, license

I'm checking the [Elsevier article sharing policies](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing) and I think there is a problem with their license of the accepted manuscript (post-review article). Indeed, the instructions say:

> Authors can share their accepted manuscript:
>
> Immediately
>
> - via their non-commercial personal homepage or blog

However,

> After the embargo period
>
> - via non-commercial hosting platforms such as their institutional repository

I don't understand the reason of this limitation, but ok, these are the rules.

However, Elsevier requires you to add the [CC-BY-NC-ND license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/) notice into the accepted manuscript. But, here's the flaw: if I can distribute the article on my website with CC-BY-NC-ND license, this means that anyone can re-share the article without limitations (excluding commercial intent), so anyone can upload it to any non-commercial repository. This, in turns, means that I can then upload it to my university repository without embargo.

Isn't this an obvious flaw of the Elsevier's policies?

Comment: Interestingly, someone seems to have published [a paper arguing this](https://www.jcel-pub.org/article/view/54-74) a number of years ago. IANAL so cannot answer in detail about whether Elsevier can place a separate condition on the author that doesn't apply to others, or sanction the author for doing something notionally within the terms of the CC license. However, I would say that I'm not sure anyone cares that much - I've seen plenty of people post copies of papers inside embargo periods on various sites without consequence, so I think this rule is more to discourage systematic abuse (YMMV).

Comment: I don't think that Elsevier can put additional conditions to authors because the CC license says "No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits."

Comment: Just to emphasize IANAL again, but my reading of the license is that 'you' refers to the recipient of the license, not the licencor. Under a normal submission copyright would transfer to Elsevier and they would then become the licencor, so they could e.g. in principle request you comply with a condition before releasing it in that format. I'm not sure what their recourse is if you don't - they may not be able to sue you for copyright infringement, but I don't see anything in the license that would, for example, stop them blacklisting you for future submissions if you didn't comply.

Comment: Good question: I had also noticed this and wondered. My suspicion is that Elsevier does not really care about the specifics, so long as sharing author-accepted versions at scale is sufficiently inconvenient that universities continue to pay high subscription fees to access the publisher versions. (If you want a publisher who works to make your research available instead of trying it to make it harder to access, I would not recommend working with Elsevier.)

Comment: @StephenMcMahon: You may want to post an answer referring to (and summarising) this article.

Comment: The sharing policy also allows updating e.g. the arXiv version to the accepted version, so I wonder what the rationale is for demanding an embargo for institutional repositories? In many cases there is hardly any difference, and people are more likely to find the paper on arXiv anyway.

Comment: @a3nm I agree. What I suspect is that they don't want it to hit PubMed Central until after the embargo period, which is easier to search and access than individual webpages.